# Is this a Mozilla firefox keyframe animation bug?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-animations, keyframe

```
a.article:nth-child(n+2) {
animation: articleSlide .3s ease-in forwards;
opacity: 0.1;}

@keyframes articleSlide {
0% {transform: translateX(-100%);}
100% {transform: translateX(0); opacity: 1;}}
```

When i hover the  links, it doesn't behave like a link. The cursor doesn't change, and click does nothing. I found that if i remove the 'forwards' from the animation property, it resolves the issue, but other browsers including Edge still recognize the link with 'forwards' in the animation property, this seems to be a firefox only bug.

Comment: can't repro, can you post your html markup, and maybe even a live demo? Btw, if you are sure you found a bug in a browser, post a bug report to their bugzilla, or include in your question that you are after a workaround if you are.